# Не могу зайти в биос

Tags: bios

Не могу нормально заходить в биос. Во время загрузки пк, экран на котором написанно нажмите Del чтобы зайти в биос вообще пропускается и сразу на рабочий стол!
Пробовал перезапуск компа через шифт, но когда я нажимаю зайти в настройки UFFI, просто заходит на рабочий стол. Это дело я пофиксил тем что сбросил биос(правда при этом у меня комп не включался после этого и и мне пришлось видеокарту вытаскивать и обратно вставлять, не знаю с чем это связанно, тоже интересно), и во время загрузки пк я сново смог заходить в биос, но не на долго! Опять этот баг, который я описал выше! Я не хочу сново возиться с батарейкой, а потом и с видюхой из за бага, что делать?

Comment: Может клавиша Del не работает? Попробуйте сменить клавиатуру.

Comment: Или батарейка разрядилась и в БИОСе при выключении устанавливаются кривые значения. Попробуйте сменить батарейку.

Comment: Del точно работает, а батарейку я менял. Получилась таже фигня, и я вернул нынешную(просто я только недавно купил мат плату и батарейка новая)

Comment: Если плата новая, то поменяйте по гарантии.